# Why does the third access to this array return null?

Tags: arrays, scala, null, nullpointerexception

I'm writing tetris in Scala as an exercise and I came around this strange behavior:

```
abstract class Orientation(protected val index: Int) {
  private[Orientation] val impls: Array[Orientation] = Array(OrientedLeft, OrientedUp, OrientedRight, OrientedDown)

  def rotateCounterClockwise = impls(
      if (index == 0) 3
      else index - 1
  )

  def rotateClockwise = impls((index + 1) % 4)
}

object OrientedLeft extends Orientation(0) {
  override def toString = "Left"
}
object OrientedUp extends Orientation(1) {
  override def toString = "Up"
}
object OrientedRight extends Orientation(2) {
  override def toString = "Right"
}
object OrientedDown extends Orientation(3) {
  override def toString = "Down"
}

object Test extends Application {
  var orientation: Orientation = OrientedUp

  for (i <- 0 until 20) {
    println("Oriented to: "+ orientation)
    orientation = orientation.rotateClockwise
  }
}
```

Running Test gives this output:

```
Oriented to: Up
Oriented to: Right
Oriented to: Down
Oriented to: null
```

Followed by an java.lang.NullPointerException obviously. I mean: What the hell is going on here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just move `impls` in a companion object:

```
object Orientation {
  private val impls: Array[Orientation] = Array(OrientedLeft, OrientedUp, OrientedRight, OrientedDown)
}
abstract class Orientation(protected val index: Int) {
  import Orientation._
  def rotateCounterClockwise = impls(
      if (index == 0) 3
      else index - 1
  )

  def rotateClockwise = impls((index + 1) % 4)
}
```

The reason why you had this error is that you have circular initializaiton dependencies: everytime you instantiate `Orientation`, you access the four `Orientation` singletons.
Simply put, accessing `OrientedUp` forces its instantiation, which in turn forces the instantian of all four singletons, including `OrientedUp` itself, which is still being constructed.
This is why you get null for this "still being constructed" value.

Comment: Wow, now that I have an explanation it seems very obvious. Thank you ;)

Answer (score 2):

This is probably an initialisation problem. Each instance of `Orientation` has an array of `OrientedX`-objects, who are themselves instances of `Orientation`. Scala `object`s are initialised lazily, but that triggers population the `impls` array with objects that are currently being initialised. Hence the `null` entry.

Do what Régis suggested or mark `val impls` as `lazy`.

Comment: Marking impl lazy works too, though going for a companion object is more efficient (and what I want in this case) if I'm not mistaken. Thank you very much ;)